# Understanding BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar in Concurrent code

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ghc

I [asked this question](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2011-July/020603.html) on the ghc-users mailing list and got some helpful responses, but still don't understand what is happening in this code.

Essentially I am trying to understand how I can catch the exception BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar to restore a lock that may have not been returned, and to understand this exception in general.

Here is some single-threaded code that does just that:

```
-- This raises the exception only once and the lock is successfully restored:
main1 = do
    lock <- newMVar ()
    lockPrint "good1" lock
    takeMVar lock 
    putStrLn "main: took lock but didn't return it!"
    -- exception is raised and lock is restored here:
    lockPrint "good2" lock
    -- no exception raised:
    lockPrint "good3" lock
    readMVar lock
    putStrLn "great success"

lockPrint :: String -> MVar () -> IO ()
lockPrint name v =  takePrint `finally` put 
    where put = putMVar v () >> putStrLn (name++": replaced lock")
          takePrint = do
               e <- try $ takeMVar v :: IO (Either BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar ())
               let printExc = putStrLn . ((name++": ")++) . show
                   printSuccess = const $ putStrLn (name++": success")
               either printExc printSuccess e
```

And here is the version of main that exhibits the behavior I don't understand. In particular I'm not quite sure why the exception is being raised in main, although I see that the threads aren't really being scheduled as I imagine.

```
main0 = do
    lock <- newMVar ()
    forkIO $ lockPrint "good1" lock

    threadDelay 100000
    takeMVar lock
    putStrLn "main: took lock but didn't return it!"

    -- raises blocked indefinitely exception
    forkIO $ lockPrint "good2" lock

    -- this should raise no exception if we were successful above:
    putStrLn "main: long pause..."
    threadDelay 2000000
    readMVar lock
    putStrLn "great success"
```

I'm sorry I'm having trouble coming up with a simpler example. The above was compiled with: `ghc --make -threaded -fforce-recomp experiments.hs`

---

EDIT: Edward Z. Yang wrote a really lucid blog [post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/07/blockedindefinitelyonmvar/) on this today here. The upshot being that this exception can't really be relied on for doing anything fancy.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to handle `BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar` doesn't sound like a good idea in the first place. It's easier to use [`withMVar`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#v%3awithMVar) to ensure that the contents of the `MVar` is always returned. With that, you shouldn't get this exception in the first place, unless you have a deadlock (which should be considered a bug and should be fixed in the code).

Comment: Isn't this exactly the problem STM was designed to solve?  Why bother with `withMVar` and manually ensuring you avoid deadlocks when the computer can do it for you?