# How does the RTS detect that a thread is blocked indefinitely on an MVar operation?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I have this code

```
mvarToList :: MVar (Maybe a) -> IO [a]
mvarToList mv = do
    mby <- takeMVar mv
    case mby of
        Nothing -> return []
        Just x  -> do
            xs <- unsafeInterleaveIO (mvarToList mv)
            return (x : xs)
{-# NOINLINE mvarToList #-}

streamQuery_ :: FromRow a => Connection -> Query -> IO [a]
streamQuery_ conn q = do
    mv <- newEmptyMVar
    void $ forkIO $ do
        fold_ conn q () (\_ x -> putMVar mv (Just x))
        putMVar mv Nothing
    mvarToList mv
```

It uses the `postgresql-simple` library which provides a `fold_` function. It allows you to provide a function that's ran on every row of the query's result. The internal implementation is such that if the provided function blocks, the next result won't be fetched (modulo batching).

What I've done here is basically attached the evaluation of an element of the list to `takeMVar` which gives me a lazy list that streams results from the DB.

The problem here is leakage. The only way I can hope to avoid any leaks is if SOMEHOW garbage collecting the list results in the RTS determining that the fetching thread is blocked forever (since nothing will be taken from the MVar anymore) and throws an exception to it. Maybe I could even catch that exception and handle cleaning up?

Comment: The RTS can determine that a thread is blocked indefinitely if a thread has the only reference to that MVar and is blocked (possibly if all threads owning a reference are blocked; not sure). It's possible to write simple examples of deadlocks that the RTS can't detect. You won't be able to recover a thread once BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVAr is raised; you can catch it and try to do stuff, but it will still be GC'd. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6847307/176841

Comment: An `MVar` is just the wrong control structure - you probably want a `Chan`. Trying to recover from a concurrency deadlock is the wrong thing to do. Furthermore, the `Maybe` does nothing here - you always write `Just ..` and finally write a single `Nothing` - just replace `MVar (Maybe a)` with `Chan a` and use `getChanContents`.

Comment: @user2407038 I'm pretty sure you misunderstood. I'm relying on the blocking behavior. I can't get that with Chan.

Comment: I did indeed understand. Relying on the blocking behavior of MVar in this way is the wrong thing to do. You must rewrite your program logic to not rely on it - or else deal with ungraceful exits (crashing on BlockedIndefinitely) and rampant memory leaks, as you simply won't be able to bully GHC into doing something with an `MVar` that it cannot do.  (Well, you might be able to - that doesn't make it a proper solution)

Comment: @user2407038 A "proper" solution doesn't have the semantics OR the interface that I want. I would love to avoid the whole exception catching thing though.